# Symfony 3.3.9 - app.user.roles doesn't get role_admin

Tags: symfony, security, user-roles

i've a problem to get role_admin or role_user in twig.

if `{{ dump(app.user) }}` then [image]

AND

if `{{ dump(app.user.roles) }}` then [image]

Then `{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}` not working
So, where is the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if value exists (same as `in_array()` in PHP):

```
{% if 'ROLE_ADMIN' in app.user.roles %}
```